# Change text color if radio button is checked with jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css

How can I change the text color of the  if the checkbox is checked please ?

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="cb" name="cb" value="cb" checked="">
    <label for="cb">My item</label>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `checked` pseudo-class.

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```